# Referencing library types in Typescript declaration files (without importing globals)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-definitions, typescript-declarations

### Background

I've been trying to contribute some additions to the Typescript definitions for Mocha. Mocha's `Runner` inherits from NodeJS `EventEmitter`. In my `.d.ts` file, I expressed this by adding:

```
/// <reference types="node" />
```

and declaring the type:

```
interface IRunner extends NodeJS.EventEmitter
```

This worked for my purpose, however after my original PR was merged, it was backed out because referencing Node's typings like this causes some globals to be set (`setTimeout` in this case), which caused conflicts with other projects.

### Repro

The project that was broken by the change was `pjax-api`, the steps to repro are:

1. `git clone https://github.com/falsandtru/pjax-api`
2. `npm install`
3. Install with npm any typing that includes either `/// <reference types="node" />` (examples: `@types/asynciterator`, `@types/couchbase`, `@types/mocha@2.2.45`); or `import * as events from 'events';`(e.g. @types/artillery)
4. Build the project with `npx tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json`

Outcome:

```
node_modules/spica/throttle.ts(7,5): error TS2322: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.
node_modules/spica/throttle.ts(28,5): error TS2322: Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

### The question

Is there a way, from within a `.d.ts` file, to make reference to a type in another `.d.ts` file, without bringing into scope all the other things from that typing that I don't want?

And, as a followup question, does that make the other example typings as broken as my original change?

### What worked

I've managed to work around this in two ways, neither totally satisfactory:

1. **Copy and paste Node signatures into the Mocha definition file**. Not DRY, prone to mistakes, will get out of sync, etc.
2. **Create a separate, local .d.ts which gets merged with the official definition**. This works for me and has the benefit of not polluting other consumers. 
   As it directly refers to the type being consumed, it will be easy to keep in-sync. However it must be manually set up in every project that wishes to use it (and because it's local, nobody else can benefit from it). And finally, `IRunner` *does* extend `EventEmitter` - so I feels like I ought to be able to express this in the typings.

Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately `d.ts` files are an all or nothing affair

Comment: @titian Thanks. That's unfortunate, but good to know. I guess I can continue with one of the workarounds mentioned